# Is it currently possible to batch inserts with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate 4.2.21.Final. In the file "BatchingBatch.java" stands the following comment:

> // IMPL NOTE : Until HHH-5797 is fixed, there will only be 1 statement in a batch

How actual is this comment? I have tried setting Hibernate properties to allow batching:

```
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "1000");
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.order_inserts", "true");
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.order_updates", "true");
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data", "true");
```

but Hibernate still executes every single statement in a separate batch. Is the reason of this behaviour that this is altogether disabled in my current Hibernate version, or is it happening because I am using a custom ID generator class? Is there a later version of Hibernate where I can batch statements while using a custom ID generator?